Does anyone know how to find the year and model for a bmx frame?
I'm buying a bike from someone. It's a fit for sure but I can't find the model for it. Does anyone know how to look it up?
Downtube has an embossed stamp that says FIT on the underside where the headtube and the down tube connect.
It has removable brake tabs.
Bottom bracket-mid
1 side... YB5I1682
The other side... F18-CD-F
I think its a 2018 too... If that helps.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Serial numbers aren't that useful, but if you can include some photos those might help judge the date.

How do I do that?

Does this answer your question? How can I tell what year my bike was made?

Hi, To attach photos to your question, you need a digital photo and if you edit your question at the top of the editor menu there is a logo to attach photos.  Once you click on the logo then you can browse your computer to locate the photo and attach.
